# Xml document gets written twice rather than overwriting through an in-memory stream

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to open an  archive Xml file (inside a zip file but not extracting it to a physical directory) in an in-memory stream then making changes to it and saving it. But archive xml file doesn't get overwritten rather it gets two copies of Xml data. One copy is the original copy of Xml data and the other one is changed/modified/edited copy of Xml data in the same archive file.
Here is my code, please help me overwrite the existing Xml data with the changes made rather than having 2 copies of Xml data in the same archive xml file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string rootFolder =     @"C:\Temp\MvcApplication5\MvcApplication5\Package1";
  string archiveName = "MvcApplication5.zip";
  string folderFullPath = Path.GetFullPath(rootFolder);
  string archivePath = Path.Combine(folderFullPath, archiveName);
  string fileName = "archive.xml";

  using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(archivePath, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
  {
      var archiveFile = zip.GetEntry(fileName);
      if (archiveFile == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentException(fileName, "not found in Zip");
      }

      if (archiveFile != null)
      {
          using (Stream stream = archiveFile.Open())
          {
              XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
              IEnumerable<XElement> xElemAgent = doc.Descendants("application");
              foreach(var node in xElemAgent)
              {
                  if(node.Attribute("applicationPool").Value!=null)
                  {
                      node.Attribute("applicationPool").Value = "MyPool";
                  }
              }

              doc.Save(stream);
          }

          Console.WriteLine("Document saved");
      }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Well, you're opening the file, reading from it, then writing to it *at the same point* (i.e. after the existing data).

Comment: @Jon I know but what I don't know is how to get rid of this problem

Comment: I don't know either, but that's *why* it's happening. This isn't really XML-specific - it's more about ZipArchive than anything else.

Comment: so shall i go ahead and unzip it somewhere or in the same location where my zip is existing then update archive xml file and re-zip it and also delete the older existing zip file...Does this make sense....

Answer (score 1):

You are first reading the XML data from the stream and then writing to the same stream, which is pointing to the end of the file. To illustrate, let's say the old file contains `ABCD` and we want to replace this with `123`.

The current approach would result in `ABCD123`, since the stream is pointing to the last char in `ABCD`.

If you reset the stream to position 0 (`stream.Seek(0)` before writing the changed file, the file would contain `123D`, because it wouldn't reduce the file length.

The solution is to delete your old `ZipArchiveEntry` and create a new one.

Comment: Actually it worked for me since I was doing some updates and writing back to the same stream so Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin) function updated the existing Xml with changes made and I don't see 123D. All I see now is 123...Though not something expected but I'm not sure why I'm not getting 123D

Comment: Because your new file is longer? It could be dangerous

Comment: And when I say changes that means I didn't include or exclude new elements in my Xml file all I did just changed the value of one of the attributes from "Pool" to "MyPool"...I guess thats why I'm not facing any length issues...Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If its dangerous, then can anyone suggest me how to delete old ZipArchiveEntry and create a new using the in-memory stream?

Comment: Found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385973/why-does-overwriting-an-xml-file-create-an-extra-end-tag..Which says that doc.Save(stream);
stream.SetLength(stream.Position);
stream.Close();   This simple code will fix the length problem.

Comment: Why would this be "the solution" @Bas ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue just now, and I fixed it by adding this first line:

```
                        stream.SetLength(0);
                        xmlDoc.Save(stream);
```

edit: I see you came across the same solution as you mentioned in the comments of the previous answer. You can add an answer to your own question. It would have helped someone like me :]